# Empty rails parameters in custom session controller in call from Android app

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to login to my web app from a mobile app and I'm getting a server error (500), and the parameters on the ruby side are empty. I find this strange because I can register fine using the same process, that is sending data as JSON and running the create action in the controller.

Is there a step I'm missing between where the ruby app receives the JSON and populates the parameters?

Here is the cotroller:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:app_session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:app_session][:password])
      respond_with do|format|
        format.json { render json: user }
      end
    else
      respond_with do|format|
        format.json { render json: { :info => "Failed" }}
      end
    end
end
```

Here is the java code: (I know the passwords are out in the open, this will be addressed)

```
@Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(myurl);

                //json.put("success", true);
                json.put("email", mUserEmail);
                json.put("password", mUserPassword);

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);

                try {
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
                    httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                    httppost.setEntity(se);
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(temp);

                    value = true;
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

            }
            return value;
        }
```

EDIT: Here are the Heroku Logs:

```
Started GET "/app_session" for 62.40.34.218 at 2013-05-20 19:14:01 +0000
Processing by AppSessionController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"app_session"=>{}}
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented some code in Android and it looks like this:

```
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(login_url);
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        post.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        JSONObject send_json = new JSONObject();
        send_json.put("login", uname);
        send_json.put("password", pwd);
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
        root.put("app_session", send_json);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(root.toString());


        Log.i("send_json", send_json.toString());
        post.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
```

It looks only difference in setting headers. I have used addHeader() while you have used setHeader(). Though I am not expert in android but above code was working for me.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks I'll try it now. What is the value of 'root' in the snippet?

Comment: I have updated answer. It was json object that you are willing to send

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. No joy with it though. Still empty params on the ruby end. It's printing the JSON in the log though. Thanks again.

Comment: can you show me the rails server log when you are sending the request ?

Comment: I edited my original question to include the Heroku logs from a login request. It is now reading status code 200, which I only just noticed.

Comment: it should a post request, It seems get request. another thing is how do you create json in android with root as app_session ? I have update d my answer for root json

Comment: Good catch. I don't know what happened there. I am definitely POSTing the request. I'll look into it...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I still have not sorted this out. I will post a new question on why my Android HTTP post request is being interpreted as a GET request on the ruby server.

Comment: ok, if possible please accept the answer if you find this useful. Thanks.